# Using CoreML to infer on Metal Texture subregions

Tags: ios, swift, metal, coreml, metalkit

I am building an iOS app that renders frames from the camera to Metal Textures in real time. I want to use CoreML to perform style transfer on subregions of the metal texture (imagine the camera output as a 2x2 grid, where each of the 4 squares is used as input to a style transfer network, and the output pasted back into the displayed texture). I am trying to figure out how to best use CoreML inside of a Metal pipeline to fill non-overlapping subregions of the texture with the output of the mlmodel(hopefully without decomposing the mlmodel into an MPSNNGraph). Is it possible to feed a MTLTexture or MTLBuffer to a coreML model directly? I'd like to avoid format conversions as much as possible (for speed).

My mlmodel takes CVPixelBuffers at its inputs and outputs. Can it be made to take MTLTextures instead?

The first thing I tried was: cutting the given sample buffer into subregions (by copying the pixel data ugh), inferring on each subregion, and then pasting them together into a new sample buffer which was then turned into a MTLTexture and displayed. This approach did not take advantage of metal at all, as the textures were not created until after inference. It also had alot of circuitous conversions/copy/paste operations that slow everything down.

The second thing I tried was: send the camera data to the MTLTexture directly, infer on subregions of the sample buffer, paste into the current displayed texture with MTLTexture.replace(region:...withBytes:) for each subregion. However, MTLTexture.replace() uses the cpu and is not fast enough for live video.

The idea I am about to try is: convert my mlmodel to an MPSNNGraph, get frames as textures, use the MPSNNGraph for inference on subregions, and display the output. I figured i'd check here before going through all of the effort of converting the mlmodel first though. Sorry if this is too broad, I mainly work in tensorflow and am a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: My suggestion would be to skip Core ML and use Metal to run the model since you're already using Metal for rendering anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've had the feeling going full metal is the right approach. Do you know how metal compares to coreml as far as speed is concerned? The only reason I want to stick with coreml is the inclusion of batch processing in iOS 12. I can't intuit if batch processing of  N subregions will be faster than N metal graphs.

Comment: In my experience Metal is much faster than Core ML. Not sure why. But Metal can also do batches, so that shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Excellent! I did not realize metal could handle batches. thank you!